# Bootstrap Nav Bar Mobile Expand Button Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working with this bootstrap nav bar. When resizing the width the window below about 767px or so it takes all the nav bar links and displays an expand button instead. Basically for mobile users. That is the correct behavior and what I'm expecting.

But when clicking on that new mobile expand button nothing happens. I want it to expand and show a menu with all the links that were removed in the nav bar. For example [this page](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). When resizing the width of the window smaller it creates that button and it is clickable. That is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have created a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/fishcharlie/pen/oLEXNK). I have also listed a small snippet of my code below. But the [codepen](http://codepen.io/fishcharlie/pen/oLEXNK) gives a better interactive example of what is going on. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and why that expand button isn't clickable?

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to load the jQuery library too.  The answer at the following link may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189481/bootstrap-hamburger-menu-not-working/38189610#38189610

Comment: @GoMega54 That worked but the order of the links are wrong in that answer seems like. Also needed to point to the navigation menu's container as Dejan Lacmanovic said. Feel free to submit an answer and I will upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data-target="#navigationbar"
```

should point to your navigation menu container.

So, in your case, it should be:

```
data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

Comment: That worked but also needed to add the jQuery library and bootstrap js as GoMega54 said. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to load the jQuery library and Bootstrap JS library for the drop down menu to work on mobile screens.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```